# How can I find a list of entities by multiple possible values (Using or in Spring Data)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have a table of users and I want to get users of certain type (type 2 and type 3 for example).

If I wanted to find by Type 2 , the repository interface would have a method

```
List<User> user = userDao.findByType(2);
```

I could get the users for type 2 and 3 by running the above method twice.

But I was wondering if it is possible to get the result set in one queury.. Something along the lines of

```
List<Long> types = new List<Long>();
types.add(2);
types.add(3);
List<User> usersOfType2And3 = userDao.findByType(types);
```

Comment: Have you tried it? AFAIK that should simply work.

Comment: I just ended up using userDao.findByTypeIn(types);

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of Criteria api for same,

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(User.class);
Criterion crit1 = Restrictions.eq("type", new Integer(2));
Criterion crit2 = Restrictions.eq("type", new Integer(3));

crit.add(Restrictions.or(crit1, crit2));

List<User> usersList = crit.list();
```